# how to show the list of item in related to search word in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contacts

i want to show the list of item  which contain search alphabets (alphabets  in Search(EditText))

Example:
1) [a] -----> i enter Alphabet "a" in  search(Edit Text)
and i want to show the list of item related to that alphabet as shown in below

result :
       **a**ton
       b**a**toon
       r**a**o
       Rob**a**t

2) [at]---> i add "t" in EditText
i want to show the result related to "at"
as show in below (in list)
likt this
result :
       **at**on
       b**at**oon
       Rob**at**

i have list of parsed item and i want to search and show the item (When in enter text in Edit text i want to show the result related to that particular world )...

Comment: kadam, is your data stored in database?

Answer (score 0):

This would be my suggestion, then you just need to overwrite your toString with the right value.

```
protected ArrayList<Object> searchItems(String cs){
        ArrayList<Object> resultList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for(Object e:mDataList){
            if(e.toString().contains(cs)){
                resultList.add(e);
            }
        }
        return resultList;
    }
```